# Converting JSON to POJO class

Tags: json, jackson, pojo

I  have been struggling with converting the below json .

1. Is the data class  should be mapped as Map<String,Object>.Then use Object mapper class to all values?What is the best way  to map below pojo

Json Response

```
{ 
 "data": {       
     
        "Order": [
        {
            {
                "Property1" : Number1
                "Propery2": Number 2
            },
                   
                "Lines": [
                    {
                        "Id": "123456",
                        "itemDescription": "Green glass",
                        
                    }
                ],
                "date": "",
                "updateDate": ""
        }
            
        ]      
       
    }
}
```

Data class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Details {
    public Map<String,Object> data;

    
}
```

Comment: Hi, please add code trying that mapping, and the resulting error